# How to load image from background.js to background.html?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension.
Now the extension is making an API call every hour and getting and image.
I want to save said image in chrome.storage.local.

However, the image is pretty big so I am compressing aka resizing the image with the use of a **canvas**.

This is why I am trying to inject the src (which I get from the API call) to an image. I thought I would be able to inject into an image tag that exists within my background.html.

this is my manifest

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "moodflow",
  "short_name": "moodflow",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0.10",
  "author": "Walter J. Monecke",
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "hot-reload.js", "background.js"],
    "pages": ["background.html"]
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "alarms",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "activeTab",
    "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api",
    "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random",
    "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/*"
  ]
}
```

and this is my jQuery AJAX in **background.js**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random",
    type: 'get',
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: "client_id=29b43b6caaf7bde2a85ef2cfddfeaf1c1e920133c058394a7f8dad675b99921b&collections=281002",
    success: (response) => {
        alert('successful API');
        alert(response);
        // insert src into img 
        $('#source_img').css('display', 'none');


        $('#source_img').on('load', function() {
            alert('Image has loaded!');
            //compressImageAndSave();
        }).attr('src', response.urls.raw);
      },
        error: () => {
          alert('getPictureApi AJAX failed');
        }
    });
```

and this is my **background.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="" id="source_img">
  </body>
</html>
```

I think my mistake is that I am assuming that my background.js can interact with my background.html.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"scripts"` in the background page declaration actually builds an empty auto-generated html page so your background.html is never used. Simply remove `"scripts"` and include the js files via `<script>` tags.

Comment: @wOxxOm You mean removing my background.js file altogether? The tasks in background.js should happen even if the extension is not open.

Comment: Eh???? I mean `"scripts"` key in your manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am sorry if I am not understanding. You mean just leaving the manifest like this? `"background": {
    "./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "hot-reload.js", "background.js"
   
  },`

Comment: No, it would be invalid syntax. Check the documentation for the background page. I thought I've explained perfectly clear but obviously I'm bad at explaining.

Comment: BTW, it's not `"pages"` and an array, but `"page"` and a single string value.

Comment: @wOxxOm what is up with the sarcasm LOL by doing what you said to include script tags then I cannot do background tasks. So no I dont understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be only one background page.
Currently you try to declare two background pages: `"scripts"` creates an autogenerated empty page and `"pages"` is an invalid declaration of a normal background page.

Remove the `"scripts"` section, link the js files via `<script>` tags in your html, use the correct `"page"` declaration with a single value.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "moodflow",
  "short_name": "moodflow",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0.10",
  "author": "Walter J. Monecke",
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "alarms",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "activeTab",
    "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api",
    "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random",
    "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/*"
  ]
}
```

**background.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="" id="source_img">
    <script src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hot-reload.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and **background.js** unchanged.

Comment: Thank you both for the help! It works perfectly! I am sorry if I did not understand at the beginning. I have been only coding for 3 months.

Comment: The merit is all @wOxxOm's. We've all been there, keep coding :)